# Adding coat of paint after a few weeks

Tags: drywall, painting, sanding, priming

I painted my drywall with a satin paint a couple of weeks ago but found some dings that need to be mudded and I have done that and have spot primed and put a single coat over the patches. At this point do I need to sand and/or prime the whole wall or can I just put a new coat over the entire wall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the wall is still clean it should be no problem to paint over without priming.

- You may need another coat on the patches first otherwise they may show through    as lighter spots. (depends on the wall color)
- Then some very light sanding with 120 grit - just quick scuff really
- Then wipe with a tack cloth to remove any dust